# BASH: Pause and resume a child script

Tags: bash, signals, wait, resume, pausing-execution

I want to control a child script somehow. I am making a master script which spawns many children scripts and need to `RESUME` and `PAUSE` them on demand.

**Child**

```
Do stuff
PAUSE
Cleanup
```

**Parent**

```
sleep 10
RESUME child
```

Is this possible?

**AS PER SUGGESTIONS**

Trying to do it with signals while the child runs in the background doesn't seem to work.

script1:

```
#!/bin/bash

"./script2" &
sleep 1
kill -2 "$!"
sleep 1
```

script2:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "~~ENTRY"

trap 'echo you hit ctrl-c, waking up...' SIGINT
trap 'echo you hit ctrl-\, stoppng...; exit' SIGQUIT

while [ 1 ]
do
    echo "Waiting for signal.."
    sleep 60000
    echo "~~EXIT1"
done

echo "~~EXIT2"
```

Running:

```
> ./script1
```

Comment: @shellter how are they duplicate if they are totally different questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to control individual process scripts is with signals.   If you combine SIGINT (ctrl-c) to resume with SIGQUIT (ctrl-) to kill then the child process looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
trap 'echo you hit ctrl-c, waking up...' SIGINT
trap 'echo you hit ctrl-\, stoppng...; exit' SIGQUIT

while (true)
do
    echo "do the work..."
    # pause for a very long time...
    sleep 600000
done
```

If you run this script, and hit ctrl-c, the work continues.  If you hit ctrl-\, the script stops.

You would want to run this in the background then send kill -2 $pid to resume and kill -3 $pid to stop (or kill -9 would work) where $pid is the child process's process id.

Here is a good bash signals reference: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-usingtraps/

-- here is the parent script...

```
#!/bin/sh

./child.sh & 

pid=$!

echo "child running at $pid"
sleep 2
echo "interrupt the child at $pid"
kill -INT $pid # you could also use SIGCONT

sleep 2
echo "kill the child at $pid"
kill -QUIT $pid
```

Comment: I seem to be able and get this working if it's run in the foreground and I hit `CTRL+C`. If it's in the background and I `kill -INT pid` it just exists!?

Comment: I just added a parent script to demonstrate. Hope that helps.

Comment: As a reminder for everyone else with the same issue, I would like to point out that you should use `SIGCONT` to resume the job as that's what it's intended to.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a named pipe per child:

```
mkfifo pipe0
```

Then redirect `stdin` of the child to read from the pipe:

```
child < pipe0
```

to stop the child:

```
read _
```

(the odd `_` is just there for `read` to have a place to store the empty line it will read).

to resume the child:

```
echo > pipe0
```

A more simple approach would be to save the stdin which gets passed to the child in form a pure file descriptor but I don't know the exact syntax anymore and can't google a good example ATM.